# Is there a way to extend an ActionBar.Tab?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-actionbar, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a generic `ActionBar.Tab` class that would hold some of the common logic for my tabs. 
The problem is that `ActionBar.Tab` class is an abstract class, so if I want to extend it I actually need to put all of the implementation logic in it.

When I create a new Tab using `ActionBar.NewTab()` I get an object of the following type: `com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl@656485c8`.

I found a class called `ActionBarImpl` in in com.android.internal.app package, but was not able to find it in Xamarin.

So the question is, which class should I inherit from in order to add additional functionality to `ActionBar.Tab`?

Comment: `ActionBar.Tab`is deprecated in android L, use other things.

Comment: @mmlooloo Which other one would you suggest?

Comment: FragmentTabHost, TabHost, and other library on github